# Slow opening hamburger menu

Tags: css, animation, menu, transform

I've been struggling with getting my hamburger menu to slowly open. It took me a long time to even create it. :) Can anyone tell me if this CSS code allows for having it gradually open?

http://codepen.io/kiddigit/pen/EKRgQz

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
    body {
        background-color: #white;
    }
    img {max-width: 100%; padding-bottom: 10px;
    }
    h1 {
        font-size: 30px;
    }


.wrapper {
    border: 0px;
    padding: 1px;
    background-color: white;
}
    .content {
        background-color: white;
        border: none;
        margin-left: 100px;
        margin-right: 100px;
    }

    .menu-btn div{
         float: left;
         padding-right: 0px;
         margin-top: 0em;
         line-height: 1.2;
         font-size: 18px;
         font-weight: 200;
         vertical-align: middle;
         z-index: 99;
    }

    .menu-btn span {
         display: block;
         width: 25px;
         height: 4px;
         margin-bottom: 5px;
         background: rgb(0,0,0);
         z-index: 99;
    }

        .menu-btn span:last-of-type {
            margin-bottom: 0;
        }

    .responsive-menu{
         display: none;
         overflow: hidden;
    }

    .responsive-menu ul {
          width: 80px;
          float: left;
          margin-right: 0;
          margin: 0;
    }

    .main-nav {
        border: none;
    }

    a {
        font-size: 10px;
        color: white;
    }

    .responsive-menu li {
        padding-left: 5px;
        font-size: 10px;
          line-height: 25px;
          list-style-type: none;
          background-color: black;  
    }

    .expand {
        display: block !important; 
    }
```

Comment: CSS can't make gradual change from display: none to diplay: block. Use jquery for that with function toggleSlide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$( '.menu-btn' ).click(function(){
    $('.responsive-menu').slideToggle('slow');
});
```

UPD: Smooth appearing of element when it changes `display` from `none` to `block` can't be achieved with CSS. JQuery has some functions for that, [toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) and [slideToggle()](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/). slideToggle looks better for dropdown as it changes height of element from 0 to its natural height. In brackets you can add animation speed, `slow` is equal to 600 milliseconds, time in milliseconds also can be used: `$('.responsive-menu').slideToggle(500)`

Comment: Please explain how your answer solves the problem, it will help everyone understand your solution with more clarity and for future reference.

Comment: @Aziz Edited my answer